# Plot Option Precedence while combining Plots with Show[]

Tags: plotting, graphics, functions, options, faq

I like to build sophisticated plots by combining simpler ones with `Show[]`. Typically this involves setting non-default Plot-Options with the different Plot-Commands, like

```
Show[ ListPlot[ ,Op1], Plot[ ,Op2], Op3]
```

Unfortunately the `Show[]` command is not commutative, as

```
Show[ Plot[ ,Op2], ListPlot[ ,Op1], Op3]
```

can produce different results. My expectation was that putting settings in `Op3` should overwrite the ones in `Op1` and `Op2` however this does not work with options like `PlotMarkers` which are only available within `ListPlot[]`.

The description of the `Show[g_1, g_2, g_3, ... ,g_i]`-command gives only two hints:

> Options explicitly specified in Show override those included in the graphics expression.

and

> The lists of non-default options in the `g_i` are concatenated.

I’m not sure what this precisely means. Is

```
Show[ ListPlot[ ,Op1], Plot[ ,Op2], Op3]
```

equivalent to

`Show[ ListPlot[ ,Union[Op1,Op2]], Plot[ ,Union[Op1,Op2]], Op3]`?

while `Op3` overwrites whatever is in `Union[Op1,Op2]`?

And there is one more question: In

```
Show[ g_1, g_2, g_3, ..., g_i ]
```

the Plot in `g_1` seems to be treated specially as it defines the `PlotRange` for the final image generated.

**I would like to know the full set of rules how the Plot-Options are combined and to which Plot or Plots they are applied.**

Comment: Indeed, the first graphic in `Show[]` is what delineates the `PlotRange` to be followed by the other graphics, in the absence of an explicit `PlotRange` setting for `Show[]`. Compare `Show[Plot[Sin[x], {x, -1, 1}], Plot[Exp[x], {x, -2, 2}]]` and `Show[Plot[Sin[x], {x, -1, 1}], Plot[Exp[x], {x, -2, 2}], PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, All}]`.

Comment: If possible, could you maybe post the specific example that is troubling you?

Comment: Additionally, options are parsed left to right. Compare `Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2, 2}, MaxRecursion -> 1, PlotPoints -> 5, PlotPoints -> 20]` and `Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2, 2}, MaxRecursion -> 1, PlotPoints -> 20, PlotPoints -> 5]`.

Comment: This is described in the "possible issues" section of the [Show](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Show.html#30226) documentation.

Comment: @J.M. This question is on my long-standing list of open Mathematica questions. It is not connected to any specific plot. I have never been able to completely unravel the rules the govern the application of the PlotOptions.

Comment: @Simon What is written in the "possible issues" section of the Show documentation, is at best misleading. The non-default options are of course the interesting ones. But the example given there is about the default PlotRange.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**First a little background:**

All of Mathematica's plotting functions produce a `Graphics` expression (or `Graphics3D`, but let's talk about `Graphics` now).  The `Graphics` expression is simply a representation of what you see in the graphic.  You can look at it by converting the output cell to `InputForm` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd>).  For example, `Plot` will produce `Graphics` with `Line`s in it.

Some of the options to plotting functions are passed on directly to `Graphics` an affect its appearance (how its contents get rendered).  An example is `Axes`.  Some others control what the plotting function will put into the graphics.  Examples are `PlotStyle` or `PlotMarkers`.  These are specific to (and different for) each plotting function.

**How `Show` works:**

It combines several `Graphics` expressions into one.  The returned `Graphics` expression will inherit its options from the first one passed to `Show`.  In `Show` you can override some `Graphics` options directly, but of course this will only override options for `Graphics`, and not the plotting functions that produced the graphics (as those have already finished running by the time `Show` sees their output).

So

```
Show[ListPlot[... , Op1], Plot[... , Op2], Op3]
```

is equivalent to

```
Show[ListPlot[... , Op3, Op1], Plot[...]]
```

or to

```
Show[ListPlot[...], Plot[...], Op3, Op1]
```

but this is only valid for `ListPlot` options that are also `Graphics` options.  It is not valid for `PlotMarkers`.

Also note that if the same option is specified several times in the same `Graphics`, the first one takes precedence. (Thanks J. M.!)

Comment: I'd modify your last bit to `Show[ListPlot[... , Op3, Op1], Plot[...]]`; after all, `Show[]` options override.

Comment: What happens in the `Plot[...]` part?  `Plot[...,Op2,Op3]` or just `Plot[..., Op2]`?

Comment: @uli Nothing.  As far as I can tell, `Graphics`-options are lost from it.  This is because `Graphics` options usually have a default value in `ListPlot` even if they're not given explicitly.  I've yet to find a `Graphics` option that will take effect in `Plot` (i.e. `Show`'s second arg).  Non-graphics options like `PlotStyle` of course do take effect.

Comment: @Szabolcs My choice of `ListPlot` and `Plot` above was arbitrary. With "...options are lost..." you mean `Show[ P_1[...,Op1], P_2[..., Op2], Op3]` is taken as `Show[ P_1[...,Op1,Op3], P_2[..., {}]]`?

Comment: @uli Yes, exactly.  (By `{}` you mean "nothing", right?)

Comment: @Szabolcs But with `Show[Plot[x, {x, 0, 15}, PlotStyle -> Blue], 
 Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 15}, PlotStyle -> Red]]` the parabola is red, so `Op2` is not lost. And yes, the empty list `{}` should indicate "nothing" :)

Comment: @uli: that's as expected, since `PlotStyle` is not a `Graphics[]` option. The overrides happen for options that are both options of `Show[]` and the component graphics...

Comment: @J.M. I seems to me that I have to distinguish PlotOptions from GraphicsOptions.

Comment: @uli That is what I was trying to say in the first section of my answer

Answer (score 14):

Just to drive Szabolcs's points home, here are a few examples to demonstrate how `Show[]` interacts with graphics objects and options given to it.

Let's start with

```
Show[Plot[Sin[x], {x, -1, 1}], Plot[Exp[x], {x, -2, 2}]]
```

[image: sine and exponential, all defaults]

Compare this image with the output from a version with options tweaked in places.

```
Show[Plot[Sin[x], {x, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> All], Plot[Exp[x], {x, -2, 2}]]
```

[image: sine and exponential, first plot modified]

The same output is obtained from `Show[Plot[Sin[x], {x, -1, 1}], Plot[Exp[x], {x, -2, 2}], 
 PlotRange -> All]`. On the other hand, `Show[Plot[Sin[x], {x, -1, 1}], Plot[Exp[x], {x, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> All]]` gives the same output as the first version.

However,

```
Show[Plot[Sin[x], {x, -1, 1}], Plot[Exp[x], {x, -2, 2}],
     PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, All}]
```

[image: sine and exponential, option override]

and an explicit option setting in `Show[]`, as expected, overrides the `PlotRange` settings of the component graphics.

---

You don't really have to worry about

> The lists of non-default options in the `g_i` are concatenated.

See, in functions like `Plot[]`, the options, as with usual rules, are parsed left to right, and the first rule encountered that applies is the one taken. Thus, compare

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2, 2}, MaxRecursion -> 1, PlotPoints -> 5, PlotPoints -> 20]
```

[image: sine, rough plot]

and

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2, 2}, MaxRecursion -> 1, PlotPoints -> 20, PlotPoints -> 5]
```

[image: sine, smooth plot]