# Why are reference lines missing in ProbabilityScalePlot when using Show?

Tags: plotting, graphics

```
failurevalues1 = {21, 19., 23., 22., 20., 28., 25.};
failurevalues2 = {30., 28., 28., 29., 31., 28., 30.};
failurevalues3 = {344., 552., 326., 267., 382., 301., 354.};

plot1 = ProbabilityScalePlot[failurevalues1, "LogNormal", 
PlotRange -> {{10, 1000}, {1, 99}}, PlotStyle -> Red, Frame -> True,
FrameLabel -> {"Number of Cycles", "CDF"}, PlotLabel -> "Plot 1"]

plot2 = ProbabilityScalePlot[failurevalues2, "LogNormal", 
PlotRange -> {{10, 1000}, {1, 99}}, PlotStyle -> Black, 
Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"Number of Cycles", "CDF"}, 
PlotLabel -> "Plot 2"]

plot3 = ProbabilityScalePlot[failurevalues3, "LogNormal", 
PlotRange -> {{10, 1000}, {1, 99}}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"Number of Cycles", "CDF"}, 
PlotLabel -> "Plot 3"]
```

> [image: Plot1]
>   [image: Plot2]
>   [image: Plot3]

So far, so good. The individual plots look reasonable.

```
plot4 = Show[plot1, plot2, plot3, PlotLabel -> "Plot Comparison"]
```

> [image: Plot]

Here is the problem, why is only 1 reference line shown in plot4 ?
How can I display the 2 missing reference lines ?

Comment: It is related to the fact that `Show` takes only first argument's options. In this case `plot1`'s but I don't know which option is the reason.

Comment: As near as I can tell each of the 3 individual plots all have the same options regarding the display of their respective reference lines. So shouldn't Show render these plots in a combined graphics element just as they appear individually ? Why would only 2 of the 3 reference lines be rendered ?

Comment: This is simply how it works ;) http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/129/5478. Also take a look at [Show in documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Show.html?q=Show&lang=en) especially on the *Possible issues*

Comment: @Steve These 3 individual plots do not have the same options regarding the display of their respective reference lines. You can see it with `InputForm[Epilog /. Options[#, Epilog]] & /@ {plot1, plot2, plot3}`. `Epilog` is an option of `Graphics` and, of course, of any plotting function like `Plot` or `ProbabilityScalePlot`!

Answer (score 6):

Looking at `InputForm` of `ProbabilityScalePlot[...]` reveals that the dashed line is drawn by [`Epilog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Epilog.html) and therefore is dropped for all such plots except first when they are combined using `Show`. It is clearly wrong design or a bug. The workaround is to `Append` the `Epilog` to [the first argument of `Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Graphics.html) produced by `ProbabilityScalePlot` (which contains all the graphics primitives included in the figure with except to those defined by the `Prolog` and `Epilog` options). Here is a fix for `ProbabilityScalePlot`:

```
pspFix = Graphics[Append[First@#, Epilog /. Options[#, Epilog]], 
    FilterRules[Options[#], Except[Epilog]]] &;
SetOptions[ProbabilityScalePlot, DisplayFunction -> pspFix];
```

You can include it in init.m file.

After evaluating the above, reevaluating the code in question produces expected result:

[image: plot]

Comment: Alexey, thank you for your solution, I don't understand it all but it works. I don't know what is going on but this is the 2nd bug in Mathematica I identified this year alone and I am by no means a power user. The other bug was also associated with version 9. I've been using this tool off and on since version 2.2 and these are the only bugs I've personally identified.

Comment: @Steve It could be unexpected but it is not a bug. `ProbabilityScalePlot` creates this dashed line via `Epilog`, that's why `Show` skip some of them. I don't know why `Probability...` works this way but that the different question.

Comment: @Kuba It is apparent inconsistency. Isn't it a bug? Or just wrong desing? It is not the expected behavior certainly.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov It depends on the definition of bug, definitely it is not expected. I would rather say that it is strange design, but maybe it has some purpose, I don't know.

Comment: @Kuba I'm probably missing something here but why are the options in ProbabilityScalePlot particularly relevant ? Isn't it the job of Show to overlay the graphic elements no matter what the options are for the individual elements? From the documentation: Show . . . "   concatenates the graphics primitives in the Subscript[g, i], effectively overlaying the graphics." But in the example above the graphics are not being overlaid; some are altered then they are overlaid. Is this by design ?

Comment: @Steve It seems you have not checked links I put under your question. Please focus on Show>PossibleIssues in documentation center. `ProbabilityScalePlot` creates dashed line by putting it in the `Epilog`, which is an option, and `Show` cares only about first element options. That's why I've said that creating this line is a strange design, maybe for other purpose which we do not know, but still, it works well in terms of relations `Show`<->`Options`.

Comment: @Steve See this example in the Documentation: [`Show` uses the options from the first graphic](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Show.html#2061249557).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov You know what I'm curious about? Where is the information about dashing? Also, with `Options[plot1,Epilog]` the part with `Line[...]` appears marked in red color. Do you see it too?

Comment: @Kuba Yes, it is how FrontEnd (which follows undocumented preprocessing by the kernel which is based on `MakeBoxes`) interprets the styling specification. Use `InputForm@Options[plot1, Epilog]` to get rid of undesired interpretation.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of that :)

Comment: @Kuba Just for illustration of the underlying behavior try `Options[plot1, Epilog] /. Style -> style`. :)

Comment: I love this forum, I wouldn't know 10% of what I know about MMA without it :) Each day something new :)

Comment: @Kuba Another fun may be `Options[plot1, Epilog] /. Style -> "Style"`. It mimics `InputForm` in this particular case without converting everything to `String`. Another way is changing the context: ``Options[plot1, Epilog] /. Style -> My`Style``. I have generalized this idea some time ago [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6230478/590388).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Sometimes it is enough to click on the output and type something. But here nothing showed so I thought it is ordinary syntax mark. :)

Comment: @Kuba You can convert the `Cell` to `InputForm` by right-clicking on the cell bracket and selecting `Convert To` -> `InputForm`. You will find something undocumented in this particular case (and it was already discussed on this forum).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I know this, I just wasn't aware that there is something more inside this time :)

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov thank you guys, I see now that the options do matter as a "Possible Issue" as shown in the PolarPlot example. Because each of my reference lines has a different color and pair of endpoints are these differences the cause of the Options being different ? If so, I would have thought that the presence or absence of the line itself or some other intentional user edit of an option would be required for a difference to be picked up by Mathematica.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know which option is responsibile for the dashed line so let me show you brute force approach since it is too late to think :)

It involves `Overlay`:

```
i = 0;
Overlay[
  ProbabilityScalePlot[#, "LogNormal", PlotRange -> {{10, 1000}, {1, 99}}, 
                           PlotStyle -> (++i; {Red, Green, Blue}[[i]]), 
                           BaseStyle -> {15, PointSize@.02}, Frame -> True, 
                           FrameLabel -> {"Number of Cycles", "CDF"}, 
                           PlotLabel -> "Plot Comparison", ImageSize -> 500

                      ] & /@ {failurevalues1, failurevalues2,  failurevalues3}
  , All]
```

[image]

`Labels` and `Ticks` look quite sharp because of not perfect alignment.

You can avoid it.

Just specify `PlotLabel` for one plot and `FrameTicks->None` for others. But add consistent `PlotRangePadding` so the frame will fit for all of them.