# Why does the order of arguments in Show influence the result?

Tags: plotting, graphics, animation

I am wondering why there is a difference in the results from evaluating the two expressions, which differ only in the order of the arguments given to `Show`.

When I run

```
Animate[Show[spring[t], bob[t], traj], {t, 0, 20}]
```

the animation is different from

```
Animate[Show[traj, spring[t], bob[t]], {t, 0, 20}]
```

Parts of the plot get cut off, depending on the order of the arguments.

Comment: Probably because `Show` takes options from the first argument which is different for those cases.

Comment: Thank you for posting the full code.  I removed it to make the question easier to follow and more useful for future visitors, as this is a general problem and not related to the specific details of the code.  (I haven't been able to find a good duplicate though one might exist.)

Comment: From Show, "Details": "`Show[g1, g2,...]` or `Show[{g1, g2,...}]` concatenates the graphics primitives in the `gi`, effectively overlaying the graphics."  And: "The lists of non-default options in the `gi` are concatenated."

Comment: @Michael Your second citation looks like a mistake in the documentation: actually `Show` does not care about options in `gi` other than `g1` (AFAIK).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I suppose it depends on what is meant. Consider `p3 = Show[
  p1 = Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 2}],
  p2 = Plot[2 Sin[x], {x, 0, 3}, ImageMargins -> 100]
  ]; AbsoluteOptions[p1]`  The first occurrence of an option overrides later ones, which are deleted.  `ImageMargins` is set to `0.` in `p1`, which would cause `ImageMargins -> 100` to be ignored, *IF* that is how it works.  In effect, then, what you say is true, too, since the first plot seems to set every possible option, or at least the documented ones.  In any case, the doc. is at least misleading.

Comment: @Michael If your explanation is correct, we have a bug in `Show`: according to the citation, it must ignore *default* option values in the `gi` when concatenating options.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov You're right, one way or the other.  I guess I'm tired and not reading carefully.  That slipped right past me.

Comment: @Michael In any case, thank you for the citation. I did not think that the developers have in mind more correct approach than we currently have as default behavior of `Show`. It is worth to fill a bug report on this issue.

Comment: [A related question.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128)

Comment: @J.M. Similar questions are marked as a duplicate of the one you linked, [(128)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/128). Should this one be? Or perhaps merged, given the upvotes on the answer?

Comment: @Michael, marking this one as a dupe ought to be fine. Interestingly, Szabolcs answered both, but this can be excused as the older question was asked during this site's beta phase.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The order of arguments in `Show` makes a difference in two ways:

1. The `Graphics` expression produced by `Show` will inherit options from the first argument
2. The first argument will appear in the bottom layer, the last one in the top layer.

The most common problem (1) causes is that the plot range is inherited from the first argument, causing parts of the second one to be cut off.  For example:

```
plot1 = Plot[x^2/20, {x, 0, 5}]
plot2 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 5}]

Show[plot1, plot2]

Show[plot2, plot1]
```

[image]

The simplest solution is to set the option explicitly in `Show`:

```
Show[plot1, plot2, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for the simple explanation. Does (2) applies to 3D graphics?

Comment: @Sigur I don't think so.