# Issue in displaying a rotated PolarPlot with Show

Tags: plotting, graphics

I can use `PolarPlot` to generate a plot; however, I would like to rotate the plot by 90 degrees and then output the result using Show.  Here is the code

```
Y20 = 
  PolarPlot[
     Abs[Sqrt[5/(16*Pi)]*(3*Cos[Theta]^2 - 1)], 
     {Theta, 0, 2*Pi}, 
     Ticks -> None
  ]
Show[Rotate[Y20, Pi/2]]
```

> [image]

and the error

> ```
> Show::gtype: Rotate is not a type of graphics.
> ```

If I wrap `Rotate` with `Graphics` the error message I get is

> ```
> Graphics is not a Graphics primitive or directive.
> ```

Any comments will be welcomed.

Comment: What about `Rotate[Y20, Pi/2]`?

Comment: Why would `Show` be needed?

Comment: Maybe to combine with another `Graphic`?

Comment: @AndyMobley Good point. So: `Graphics[Rotate[Y20[[1]], Pi/2, {0, 0}]]` may be used in `Show`.

Comment: @Kuba: The method in your original comment certainly works. Why not make it an answer?

Comment: @Kuba Assuming that the `Show` is needed, I think your fix with an explanation of why would be useful.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries To comply with the HW reqs?

Comment: @beisarius Yo no comprendo.

Comment: @belisarius I think you are probably right, but I learned a lot from Kuba's answer. For a newbie like me, simple questions sometimes teach me a lot about Mathematica structure.

Comment: @belisarius was thinking of HardWare, but couldn't make the link. HomeWork, as an alternative, is more likely.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries You're right. Good HardWork!

Comment: @AndyMobley Yep. Mine wasn't a critic, just an observation. We see quite a lot of very bad and crazy HW problems here, many of them obviously written by teachers without the slightest idea of what "programming in Mathematica" means. And also, it's not uncommon to find outstanding and conceptually sound answers to those questions

Answer (score 5):

#### About `Rotate`

[`Rotate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Rotate.html) is a quite strightforward function; it does what you want.

You use `Rotate` on something that is not a `Graphics` primitive? No problem, it will give what you ask:

```
Rotate[longvariablename, Pi/2]
```

> [image]

More formally it performs context sensitive typesetting:

```
ToBoxes @ Graphics @ Rotate[Disk[], Pi]
ToBoxes @ Rotate[Disk[], Pi]
```

> ```
> GraphicsBox[
>      GeometricTransformationBox[ DiskBox[{0, 0}], {{{-1, 0}, {0, -1}}, Center}]
> ]
>
> RotationBox[
>     RowBox[{"Disk", "[", RowBox[{"{", RowBox[{"0", ",", "0"}], "}"}], "]"}], 
>     BoxRotation -> 3.14159
> ]
> ```

Moreover, `Rotate/GeometricTransformation` can't be used directly with `Graphics`, only with graphics primitives, that is why you get an error. You result produces something which can be boiled down to:

```
Graphics[{Graphics[Disk[]]}]
```

---

#### Your case

`Y20` is not a graphics primitive so it will be treated as above. So you see you can't pass it to [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Show.html). It's no longer just `Graphics` (*`RotationBox` is created - more at the end...*).

---

#### Solution

So what to do? We have to take graphics primitives from `Y20`, `Rotate` them and put back into `Graphics`.

You can read for example [How to examine structure of graphics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32716/how-to-examine-the-structure-of-graphics-objects) to learn more but usually it is simple; for example, `Plots` and friends (*with exclusion of `Graph`s*) are producing:

```
 Graphics[{primitives..}, options..] (*or, for more complicated like ContourPlot*)

 Graphics[GraphicsComplex[spec...], options..] (*Normal[] can convert it back to simple form*)
```

for both cases first argument is what you need. Everything is an expression so it is again straightforward:

```
Graphics @ Rotate[First @ Y, Pi/2, {0,0}] 
(*so exactly what I've said we need to do, take-rotate-put back*)
```

`Show` takes `Graphics` so you can combine it with whatever you want:

```
Show[{
      Plot[Sin[x], {x, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red],
      Graphics[Rotate[Y20[[1]], Pi/2, {0, 0}]]},
     PlotRange -> 1, AspectRatio -> Automatic, BaseStyle -> {18, Bold, Thick}]
```

[image]

Keep in mind that `Show`, as said in documentation, takes its `Options` from the first argument, here `Plot`. It doesn't matter for this context, just pointing it out. [More here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/44542/5478)

Comment: I didn't want to say more about creating graphics because I'm not informed enough. Not very important for the context too but if anyone want, it would be nice addition.