# How to rotate around z-axis a simple 3DPlot?

Tags: plotting, rotation

I am trying to `Rotate` a 3DPlot around the z-axis (in the horizontal plane). This is what I believed would work, but I think I misunderstood how Rotate works. When I change the vector {0,0,1} to {1,1,1}, nothing happens. When I change the amount of degrees, it rotates in the wrong way. If I am not wrong, ViewPoint keeps the point of view constant. I think the key is actually in the ViewPoint. Changing the first component of the vector in ViewPoint helps to have the desired rotation, but the issue is now that I get a strong zoom which I do not want. A picture below shows what I would like to achieve, keeping sizes constant.

```
 Rotate[Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi},ViewPoint->{1,1,1}], 70 Degree, {0, 0, 1}]
```

I believe `Rotate` is turning the whole image, not the single plot inside the square containing the plot.

[image]

Comment: This is 2D case but the answer should fit here perfectly: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44748/5478

Comment: @Kuba what I want is the Plot to be make a revolution

Comment: So did OP there, and I think both of you meant rotation with respect to coordinates used in plot in opposite to notebook window frame.

Comment: @Kuba i added an image, do you believe we aimed to the same?

Comment: Is this `Graphics3D[Rotate[plot[[1]], 70 Degree, {0, 0, 1}], 
 Sequence @@ Rest@plot]` what you need? Then yes.

Comment: @Kuba that is fine, but isn't there a simpler way to rotate the whole box with respect to coordinates used in plot? This is cutting part of my plot:
`Graphics3D[Rotate[plot[[1]], 70 Degree, {0, 0, 1}, {1.5, 1.5, 0}], 
 Sequence @@ Rest@plot]`

Comment: Add `PlotRange -> All` to `Graphics3D`.

Comment: @Kuba still cutting it; `PlotRange->All` must be added to `Plot`. However, this seems to be the best for my purposes:
`Graphics3D[Rotate[plot[[1]], 100 Degree, {0, 0, 1}, {1.5, 1.5, 0}], 
 Axes -> True, PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: Not true, you just need to put it before `Sequence..` because the first option takes precedence

Answer (score 2):

Answer from [Issue in displaying a rotated PolarPlot with Show](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44748/5478) used for this specific case:

```
plot = Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}, 
  ViewPoint -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

```
Graphics3D[Rotate[#, 70 Degree, {0, 0, 1}], 
   PlotRange -> All, ##2] & @@ plot
```

[image]

Comment: when adding another function, say `Cos[x y]`, and including `PlotLegends`, I get an error saying "Graphics is not a Graphics3D primitive or directive". How to include the Legends in Graphics?

Comment: I realized now that what I actually wanted is rotating the whole box in which the 3DPlot is contained. This code is allowing rotation of the 3DPlot with respect to an axis defined within the 3DPlot itself. I would like to rotate the whole box, again with respect to the axis defined within the 3DPlot. How?