# Could not combine error

Tags: plotting, rotation

I used below code to combine two objects, but there is an error:

```
Could not combine the graphics objects in Show
```

The code is:

```
ellip= Disc[];
f = Plot[Evaluate[Table[BesselJ[n, 10 x], {n, 1}]], {x, -0.375, -2}];
ff = Rotate[f, Pi/2];
Show[ellip, ff]
```

Coud anyone help to solve the problem?

Comment: While `ellip` is not defined I think it is a duplicate of [Issue in displaying a rotated PolarPlot with Show](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44748/5478), do you agree?

Comment: I added it. Could you please help? @Kuba

Comment: I think I already did, have you seen the topic? Also, assuming you meant `Disk`, your `Show[Disk[]]` is not correct at all.