# Why does the filling on my ListPlot not reach the axis for some values?

Tags: plotting, manipulate, filling

Why does

```
pPost[1, k_, p_: 2/3, p1_: 1/3, p2_: 2/3] := 
  (p p1^k (1 - p1)^(3 - k))/(p p1^k (1 - p1)^(3 - k) + (1 - p) p2^k (1 - p2)^(3 - k));
pPost[2, k_, p_: 2/3, p1_: 1/3, p2_: 2/3] := 
  ((1 - p) p2^k (1 - p2)^(3 - k))/(p p1^k (1 - p1)^(3 - k) + (1 - p) p2^k (1 - p2)^(3 - k));

Manipulate[
  Show[
    Plot[pPost[1, k, p, p1, p2], {k, 0, 3},
      PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Thin}, 
      PlotRange -> {All, {0, 1}}, 
      Ticks -> {{0, 1, 2, 3}, Automatic}],
    ListPlot[
      {{#, pPost[1, #, p, p1, p2]} & /@ Range[0, 3], 
       {#, pPost[2, #, p, p1, p2]} & /@ Range[0, 3]},
      PlotStyle -> {Green, Red}, 
      Filling -> Axis]],
  {{p, 2/3}, 0, 1},
  Delimiter,
  {{p1, 1/3}, 0, 1}, 
  {{p2, 2/3}, 0, 1}]
```

produce plots where the filling "disconnects" from the axis for some values of the `Manipulate` parameters?

---

Try `p=0.75`, `p1=0.7`, `p2=0.6`:

[image]

or (weirder) `p=p1=p2=0.5`

Comment: Didn't test but I suspect the `Show`.  Set the final plot range in the `ListPlot` too, not just in `Show`, and set it to the same in all.  Sorry if this doesn't help.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Setting `PlotRange -> {All, {0, 1}}` in `ListPlot` seems to do the trick. *Where is the need for that documented?*

Comment: I'm glad this helped.  Sorry, I don't know where this is documented.  What happens is that the lines are drawn only until the edge of the PlotRange.  When you combine two graphics with Show, the PlotRange will be inherited from the first, so the filling lines for the second might not reach the frame edge.

Comment: Related: "[Why does the order of arguments in Show influence the result?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/44542/280)"

Comment: @Szabolcs: Thanks, that looks like an answer. (Still no sign of where this is documented; I bet it isn't, or at least not well.)

Comment: Ordering of options in `Show` is documented in its help page, both in the 'Details' section as well as the 'Possible Issues'section.

Answer (score 2):

While the order of the plots in [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Show.html) makes difference, it is not the whole story.  By default, many options are set automatically at the time of execution.  In particular, `PlotRange` and `AxesOrigin`.  The settings for [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Plot.html) and [`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListPlot.html) are determined separately since they are evaluated separately.  This much I think can be inferred from the documentation, although not "easily."

When the `ListPlot` has a narrow plot height, the axes origin is moved up closer to the points.  This can be controlled by setting `PlotRange` as mentioned in the comments.  I would prefer to control it by setting

```
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}
```

in `ListPlot` to force the axes to always be at `{0, 0}`, and let the `PlotRange` be determined automatically.

Often in practice, to get two or more independent plots to look right when combined, automatically determined options often have to be set explicitly in all plots.