# Filling -> Axis leaves a gap

Tags: filling

Filling leaves a gap between the function curve and the axis

```
Show[Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], z], {z, -3, 6}], 
Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], z], {z, c=1.4, 6}, Filling -> Axis]
]
```

[image]

But for other values (e.g., c=0.5 instead of c=1.4 in the above code), the Filling is correct.  Is this a bug or am I making some subtle error?

Comment: Add `PlotRange -> All` to the second plot.

Comment: PlotRange->All works.  thanks!

Comment: Effectively duplicate of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45424/12