# The Show function consistently only shows the first graph

Tags: plotting

The whole purpose of the Show function is to be able to compare multiple graphs, but mine just plots the first one. I've cleared all, and Cleared Global multiple times--and redefined data1. This isn't the first time that it has done this, so I think it's something to do with the way I'm using the Show function. [image: These two graphs should be exactly the same]
Data1 has exactly the same x range. The y range should also be visible--in fact, it's the first graph in the picture below.

Comment: See also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44541/why-does-the-order-of-arguments-in-show-influence-the-result In short, the PlotRange is inherited from the first one. Notice the horizontal range. Workaround: set `PlotRange` in `Show` (simplest is `PlotRange -> All`).

Comment: The problem is probably due to your x axes being very different. `Show` sets the range based on the first plot it sees. When `data1` comes first, it sets the range to be 600 to 740. When your `Table` comes first, it sets the range to be 1 through 140 since there are no x-values.

If you meant for your `Table` data to have x-values ranging from 600 to 729, use `Table[{x, yourequation}, {x, 600, 729}]`. If you meant them to have different x ranges, then you'll have to set the `PlotRange` to include x values from 1 to 729.

Comment: Data1 has similar y values, and the exact same x values.

Comment: @ElizabethKaiser We don't have your `data1`, but what you show in the screenshot has a very different `x` range. If you only stored the `y` values (not `x` ones), then use `DataRange` in `ListPLot` to specify what the x range should be.