# How can I make sure that 3D plots have the exact same orientation and viewpoint?

Tags: graphics3d

**Edit** - I made the example data much smaller, so it's not so much to download.

I am trying to make animations of electronic orbitals, using functions like the ones listed [here](http://mathematica.blogoverflow.com/2013/09/plotting-electronic-orbitals-using-mathematica/).  In order to make an animation, I need for the resulting 3D image to have a stationary camera - i.e. no jumping around from frame to frame. Here are two examples that I can't get this to work on.

```
{model,polygons1,polygons2}=Get["https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jasondbiggs/474f13ef2680bf5afe1c/raw/3defa3ce25f3c10eeb7ab2836dbb50ce4b3d50a1/data.m"];

Graphics3D /@ {model, polygons1, polygons2}
```

[image]

We have a skeleton, and a group of polygons (stripped from a 3D contour plot).  I combine them and give them the same options for `ViewPoint`, `ViewVertical`, and `ViewCenter`.

```
image1 = Graphics3D[{{Red, polygons1}, model}, 
   ViewPoint -> {0.14, 0.2, -3.4}, ViewVertical -> {0.04, 0.01, -2.0},
    Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {0, 0, 3.4}];
image2 =
  Graphics3D[{{Blue, polygons2}, model}, 
   ViewPoint -> {0.14, 0.2, -3.4}, ViewVertical -> {0.04, 0.01, -2.0},
    Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {0, 0, 3.4}];
```

But when I cycle through them, they are clearly shown from different vantage points,

```
Manipulate[Show[{image1, image2}[[image]]], {image, {1, 2}}]
```

[image]

So what am I missing?  How can I make sure that every single time I create a 3D image that the view is identical?  Is there another important viewing option besides those 3?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand. Are the two image files supposed to be EXACTLY the same? The ViewXXX parms are referred to the coordinate axes, not to the image itself

Comment: There are more `View*` options: `ViewVector`, `ViewAngle`, `ViewVertical`, `ViewPoint`, `ViewCenter`, and `ViewRange` (I _think_ the first three are the ones you need to fix). Instead of setting each of these individually, you can just set the `ViewMatrix` (which in turn depends on these) and you should be fine. See this question for more, especially Heike's answer: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3528/5 (I think this fully addresses what you want to achieve)

Comment: @belisarius The two images are not exactly the same.  In particular, the blue and red surfaces are different in the images.  But the coordinate system is the same, the coordinates of the stick-and-ball model are the same.  So I should be able to make images that have the model in exactly the same spot but the surfaces move.

Comment: Ah, ok. I understand now

Comment: @rm-rf, I am not finding the page you linked to to be especially helpful.  In particular, I don't see that anyone answered the OP's question.  What I apparently want is a function that can operate on a graphics object and return the `ViewMatrix`.

Comment: @JasonB Hmmm... Did you see Heike's answer? Does using that and pressing "Print ViewMatrix" not work? I haven't tried it specifically with your objects, but I don't see why it wouldn't work. Note that Heike's answer was just an example, so to modify it to your needs, you might have to replace `Graphics3D[{gr}, ...]` with your molecules.

Comment: @rm-rf, It's taking a while to figure it out.  That function has a lot of special stuff I don't need and it's taking a bit to work it out, it definitely isn't a single change, but many changes.  Ideally, I'd like to take a 3D object which I've rotated until it's perfect, then feed that as the argument to a `FindViewMatrix` function.

Comment: I see what you mean... Sorry, I don't have time to work on repackaging Heike's code into a stand alone function, so all I can do is leave comments :( I think the core parts are the functions `tt` and `pp` (plus the functions they depend on), and the line `N[{tt[v1, vert, center, Cot[viewAngle/2]/Norm[v1]], pp[viewAngle/2]}]` gives the `ViewMatrix`. `v1`, `vert`, `center` and `viewAngle` are directly obtained from the other `View*` options. Perhaps the quantities can be obtained from solutions here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5375/5 (or as in your question)

Comment: I guess this [answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5377/131) should help you as well (it is a subset of [Yu-Sung Chang´s answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3538/131) ).

Comment: @YvesKlett, I was trying to do something along those lines, but that trick doesn't work with `ViewVector` or `ViewMatrix`. From what Yu-Sung says, there just isn't any way for the kernel to query the front end and ask for the current value of these two parameters.  I'm just working around it for now.  The issue comes up because Mathematica set the `PlotRange` for the two `ListContourPlot3D` differently, and so I set it to always span the entire `DataRange`.  This works for my problem now, but this is still a general problem with making 3D animation frames in Mathematica.

Comment: So nothing short of the complete `ViewMatrix` will help you? This *is* inconvenient with the given limitations of `AbsoluteOptions`.

Comment: @YvesKlett, to be honest, before this thread I hadn't even heard of the `ViewMatrix`.  Previously I had been able to get by with `ViewPoint`, `ViewVertical`, and `ViewCenter`.  I just need a way to make sure that when I make a  3D image via `ListContourPlot3D`, that it has the exact same viewing options as another `ListContourPlot3D`, provided they are in the same coodinate system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Users N.J.Evans and SquareOne came up with this, but I'll post it just so the question can be answered.

I had originally made these plots using the functions [here](http://mathematica.blogoverflow.com/2013/09/plotting-electronic-orbitals-using-mathematica/) and they are essentially made via commands like

```
Show[ model, ListContourPlot3D[ data, options]]
```

where `model` is the 3D chemical model and `options` would include things like `PlotRange`.  I had tried to be specific and give the exact same `PlotRange` to every molecule plot.  But it would seem that the `PlotRange` given to `ListContourPlot3D` did not directly affect the `PlotRange` of the combined graphic created with `Show`.  You can see this by

```
Charting`get3DPlotRange /@ {image1, image2}
(* {{{-277.634, 287.701}, {-170.275, 172.791}, {-135.625, 
   135.624}}, {{-276.904, 286.273}, {-170.267, 172.414}, {-115.797, 
   115.742}}} *)
```

So the answer to my original question, "What option, in addition to `ViewPoint`, `ViewAngle`, and `ViewVertical`, do I have to set to ensure that the 3D graphics viewpoint is the same?" is that you have to have the same `PlotRange` in the final display of the `Graphics3D` object.

```
Manipulate[
 Show[{image1, image2}[[image]], 
  PlotRange -> {{-278, 288}, {-170, 173}, {-136, 136}}], {image, {1, 
   2}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Well, obviously, since `Show` creates a graphic that inherits the options of the first argument (first element of first list) passed to `Show` and ignores the options of the subsequent graphics. Overriding options should always be passed to `Show` itself, not to its arguments.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP, [that's correct.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128)

Answer (score 3):

If the issue is that internally Graphics3D sets any scaling and view based on what's in the object being displayed, how about making all objects with the same "stuff" but different colors?  In other words, include all of the possible pieces but use `Transparent` for the color of the pieces not to be seen in a particular image.

```
image1 = Graphics3D[{{Red, polygons1}, {Transparent,EdgeForm[None], polygons2}, 
   model}, ViewPoint -> {0.14, 0.2, -3.4}, 
  ViewVertical -> {0.04, 0.01, -2.0}, Boxed -> False]
image2 = Graphics3D[{{Blue, polygons2}, {Transparent,EdgeForm[None], polygons1}, 
   model}, ViewPoint -> {0.14, 0.2, -3.4}, 
  ViewVertical -> {0.04, 0.01, -2.0}, Boxed -> False]

Manipulate[Show[{image1, image2}[[image]]], {image, {1, 2}}]
```

Comment: You could also just set the `PlotRange` for each image, which is effectively what you're doing by including the same data in both images.

Comment: @N.J.Evans That's got to be much more efficient than what I proposed.  You should write-up that answer.

Comment: @N.J.Evans You're right. Actually, if you just add a given `PlotRange` inside the `Show` (in `Manipulate`) it fixes the problem.

Comment: Jim, this works for 2 data sets but for hundreds it would scale poorly.  For SquareOne's suggestion, maybe we could use Charting`get3Dplotrange to figure the best plot range.

Comment: @JasonB.  No disagreement here.  It can even be sluggish for just 2 large data sets.

Comment: @JasonB Very interesting hidden func. i did not know about ! Indeed, `PlotRange@image2` (or `AbsoluteOptions[image2,PlotRange]`) is different from `Charting\`get3DPlotRange@image2`. Superimposing those 2 corresponding bounding boxes with `image2` shows that the `Absolute[...]` way does not know that `Sphere` has a radius ... But this is off topic and has been probably been discussed elsewhere.

Comment: Ugh, I should have known it would be something like this.  When I had originally created these graphics, it was like `Show[ model, ListContourPlot3D[ data, options]]` where options included the same plotrange and viewing options, but they didn't carry through to the final graphics I guess.  As SquareOne and   N.J.Evans point out, if you set the `PlotRange` on the `Show` to `MinMax /@ Transpose[Charting`get3DPlotRange /@ {image1, image2}]` then the problem disappears.  I will totally accept this answer if someone posts it.