# Fitting data to plot using errors as weights

Tags: plotting, fitting

I have some enzyme kinetics data that I want to fit to the [Michaelis-Menten curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michaelis%E2%80%93Menten_kinetics) in order to obtain the kinetic parameters of the enzyme.

Is it meaningful, statistically and functionally speaking, to use the error bars (standard deviation) of the measurements as weights in the `NonlinearModelFit` function, and are there any caveats that I need to take note of when using the function this way?

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]
rateList = 
  Transpose[{{0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 1, 3, 10}, {0, 0.0107, 0.0179, 
     0.02103, 0.0314, 0.0645, 0.0875}}];
errorList = {0.0015, 0.00043, 0.00071, 0.0043, 0.0051, 0.0050, 0.0071};
weightList = 1/errorList;
mmfit = NonlinearModelFit[rateList, a*x/(b + x), {a, b}, x, 
  Weights -> weightList]
Show[ErrorListPlot[
  Table[{rateList[[i]], ErrorBar[errorList[[i]]]}, {i, 
    Length[rateList]}], AxesLabel -> {"[Substrate] (mM)", "Activity (Units)"},
   PlotLabel -> "Michaelis-Menten Curve"], 
 Plot[{mmfit[x]}, {x, 0, 10}], Frame -> True]
```

Also, the AxesLabel property of the plot does not seem to be displaying the axes' names in the resulting plot. What am I doing wrong in this case that is preventing the axes from being correctly displayed?

[image]

Comment: The standard practice, as noted [here](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmd/section1/pmd143.htm), is to weight by variance; so, `weightList = 1/errorList^2` seems more appropriate.

Comment: You have set Frame to True so you need FrameLabels rather than AxesLabels.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. After changing my weights to use the square of the standard deviations, the curve is [now cut off](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QaNZe.jpg). I presume this is again due to some automated plot shenanigans near an asymptote, but I can't find the correct option to use in the [Plot documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) to fix this.

Comment: Put the `Plot[]` first in your `Show[]`, and move the options in `ErrorListPlot[]` out as options to `Show[]`.

Comment: ... or, possibly more easily, just add `PlotRange->Full` to the `Plot` function.

Comment: You might want to see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128) for your future reference.