# How to combine option settings in multiple plots such as Epilog/Prolog?

Tags: plotting, graphics, options

Suppose you have a program that produces plots. Later a user wishes to combine some of them with [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html). The options in the first plot will override the options in the second plot (see [Plot Option Precedence while combining Plots with Show[]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128/plot-option-precedence-while-combining-plots-with-show)). This is particularly unfortunate with options whose settings can be concatenated, such as `Prolog` and `Epilog`.

Is there some convenient way to combine such plots and at the same time combine the settings for options that can be meaningfully concatenated, such as `Prolog` and `Epilog`?

Example. Given the two plots:

```
plot1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi},
 Prolog -> {Red, Disk[{Pi/2, 0}]},
 Epilog -> {Purple, Thickness[0.05], Line[{{-Pi, 1/2}, {Pi, 1/2}}]}
 ]
plot2 = Plot[Cos[x], {x, -Pi, Pi},
 Prolog -> {Yellow, Disk[]},
 Epilog -> {Green, Thickness[0.05], Line[{{-Pi, -1/2}, {Pi, -1/2}}]}
 ]
```

The combined output should look like this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a method based on an [earlier answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/88298/121) of mine, with extensions.

```
grPat = (gr : #) | {gr : #} &[(_Graphics | _Graphics3D) ..];

mergeOp[gr__][(op_ -> fn_) | op_] := 
  op -> (#& @* fn) @ Lookup[Options /@ {gr}, op, ## &[]]

combineShow[grPat, opts_List: {Prolog, Epilog}] := Show[gr, mergeOp[gr] /@ opts]

combineShow[opts_List][grPat] := combineShow[gr, opts]
```

Basic usage defaulting to `{Prolog, Epilog}` for the options to combine:

```
combineShow[plot1, plot2]
```

[image]

Combine only `Epilog`:

```
combineShow[plot1, plot2, {Epilog}]
```

[image]

The default combination operator (`List`) works for some options but not all.  Consider the case of `PlotRange`:

```
plot3 = Show[plot1, PlotRange -> {{0, Pi}, {-1, 1}}]
plot4 = Show[plot2, PlotRange -> {{-Pi, 0}, {-1, 1}}]
```

[image]

To get the complete graphic we need to combine the `PlotRange` values in a particular way, and that can be specified like this:

```
combineShow[plot3, plot4, {Prolog, Epilog, PlotRange -> Map[MinMax]@*Thread}]
```

[image]

#### Note:

- `Map[MinMax]@*Thread` only works with complete PlotRange values; it would fail on `PlotRange -> All` for example.  I did not mean to present this as a robust way to combine `PlotRange` values, rather as an example of the use of my `combineShow` function.

`combineShow` is written to also work in postfix notation:

```
{plot1, plot2} // combineShow

{plot1, plot2} // combineShow[{Epilog}]

{plot3, plot4} // combineShow[{Prolog, Epilog, PlotRange -> Map[MinMax]@*Thread}]
```

Comment: Already +1, but I figured `PlotRange` would take a lot more code than that.

Comment: @MichaelE2 True!  I realized my simple example would not be robust but I wanted to provide it anyway.  I should have been more clear about what I wanted that to represent.  Thanks for the vote.

Comment: Oops, again, I decided `PlotRange -> (All &)` was a mistake. It's not the same as taking the smallest bounding box of the two plot ranges.  So I edited it out of my first comment.

Comment: `(#& @* fn)` is a neat trick!

Comment: @SimonWoods Thanks :-)

Comment: VERY impressive, thanks!