# PlotRange Interval

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I use the following code to show a `Histogram` with a `PDF` additionally

```
Show [Histogram[{data}, {width}, "ProbabilityDensity", ImageSize -> {820, 530}, PlotRange -> All], Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[mu, sigma], x], {x, -4.50,5.00}, ImageSize -> {820, 530}, PlotRange -> All]]
```

I have added the final picture.

Just for cosmetical points I would like to have the diagramm on the right so far that the curve will go smooth to the axis but here it is still cut at 4.

Is this possible?

thanks

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding an explicit `PlotRange` setting to `Show[]`? See [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128), for instance.

Comment: just as a feedback for others: it has worked :-)