# Does combining a plot and a region with Show override the region's options?

Tags: graphics, regions

A few simple shapes:

```
lowercover = RegionDifference[Rectangle[{-2, -2}, {2, 0}], Disk[{0, 0}, 1]];
uppercover = RegionDifference[Rectangle[{-2, 0}, {2, 2}], Disk[{0, 0}, 1]];
square1 = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}];
square2 = Polygon[{{0.5, 0}, {1.5, 0}, {1.5, 1}, {0.5, 1}}];
```

When I do the following, `Show` ignores color options (the squares show as black) in the second and third objects:

```
Show[
Plot[None, {x, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> {{-1.05, 1.05}, {-1.05, 1.05}}],
Region[square1, BaseStyle -> {FrontFaceColor -> Blue}], 
Region[square2, BaseStyle -> {FrontFaceColor -> Green}]]
```

Yet when I try this other example, `Show` honors the color options (shows blue and green) in the second and third objects:

```
Show[
Plot[None, {x, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> {{-1.05, 1.05}, {-1.05, 1.05}}],
Region[uppercover, BaseStyle -> {FrontFaceColor -> Blue}],
Region[lowercover, BaseStyle -> {FrontFaceColor -> Green}]]
```

**Why is the behavior different?**

(This is on 11.2)

**ADDENDUM:** The answers below are very helpful but I wanted to point out one one other surprising outcome:

```
blank = Graphics[{}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 1}}];
a = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}, {0, 1}}];
b = Polygon[{{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}, {1, 1}}];
c = Polygon[{{-0.36, 0.21}, {-0.36, -0.21}, {0, -0.53}, {0.64, -0.37}, {0.64, 0.37}, {0, 0.53}}]
d = Polygon[{{-0.42, 0.24}, {-0.42, -0.24}, {0, -0.56}, {0.58, -0.33}, {0.58, 0.33}, {0, 0.56}}]
Show[blank, Region[RegionDifference[a, b], BaseStyle -> {FrontFaceColor -> Green}]]
Show[blank, Region[RegionDifference[c, d], BaseStyle -> {FrontFaceColor -> Green}]]
```

The first `Show` takes the color as a directive whereas the second takes it as an option and overrides it. Now, while this is surprising, the reason is pretty clear if you just evaluate the following:

```
RegionDifference[a, b]
RegionDifference[c, d]
```

The former returns a Boolean region while the latter returns a Polygon, and that's presumably why we get different outcomes. At one point, they both returned Boolean regions (or something equivalent), but I believe the update in `RegionDifference` for 11.2 has made the behavior diverge. So `Show` is very well-behaved. `RegionDifference` is still a a bit of a mystery to me!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74971/discussion-on-question-by-shane-does-combining-a-plot-and-a-region-with-show-ove).

Comment: I would argue that the second one is the buggy behavior: `Show[Graphics[{}, BaseStyle -> Orange, PlotRange -> 2], Region[square1, BaseStyle -> {FrontFaceColor -> Blue}], Region[square2, BaseStyle -> {FrontFaceColor -> Green}]]`, and compare with the version with `uppercover` and `lowercover`.

Comment: `BaseStyle` for `Region` is not only a final's `Graphics'` options but is also passed inside the structure. And the way it is used next to `Polygon` differs whether you use `RegionDifference` or simple region. `Show` still does not care about subsequent options. But `Region` has `colorDirectives, polygon` structure inside. See remark about `PlotStyle/PlotMarkers` in linked answer.

Comment: @Kuba, I think there is at least reportable behavior here, but I'll leave voting to reopen to other people.

Comment: @J.M. let me be me then because I already wasted one reopen vote by opening/closing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll use a simpler example for this demonstration.

```
blank = Graphics[{}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 1}}];

square1 = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}];
square2 = Polygon[{{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}, {1, 1}}];

square3 = RegionDifference[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 1}], Rectangle[{1, 0}, {2, 1}]];
square4 = RegionDifference[Rectangle[{1, 0}, {3, 1}], Rectangle[{2, 0}, {3, 1}]];
```

Have a look:

```
{Show[blank, Region[square1, BaseStyle -> {FrontFaceColor -> Blue}], 
      Region[square2, BaseStyle -> {FrontFaceColor -> Green}]], 
 Show[blank, Region[square3, BaseStyle -> {FrontFaceColor -> Blue}], 
      Region[square4, BaseStyle -> {FrontFaceColor -> Green}]]} // GraphicsRow
```

[image: result 1]

Another test:

```
blank2 = Graphics[{}, BaseStyle -> {FrontFaceColor -> Pink},
                  PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 1}}];

{Show[blank2, Region[square1, BaseStyle -> {FrontFaceColor -> Blue}], 
      Region[square2, BaseStyle -> {FrontFaceColor -> Green}]], 
 Show[blank2, Region[square3, BaseStyle -> {FrontFaceColor -> Blue}], 
      Region[square4, BaseStyle -> {FrontFaceColor -> Green}]]} // GraphicsRow
```

[image: result 2]

Something screwy is going on with the option inheritance in the right side. Here's why.

Recall that feeding a `Region[]` object to `Show[]` will effectively convert it to a `Graphics[]` object:

```
{Head[Region[square3]], Head[Show[Region[square3]]]}
   {Region, Graphics}
```

and I would say that something in the conversion is causing this. Peering at the `InputForm[]` ought to be illuminating:

```
Show[Region[square1, BaseStyle -> {FrontFaceColor -> Blue}]] // InputForm
   Graphics[{Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}], {}},
            {BaseStyle -> {FrontFaceColor -> RGBColor[0, 0, 1]},
             BaseStyle -> {Hue[0.6, 0.3, 0.95]}}]
```

where we note that the conversion behaved as expected, with `BaseStyle` going as an option at the end, and thus subject to [the usual inheritance behavior](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128).

Now, for the other square:

```
Short[InputForm[tst = Show[Region[square3, BaseStyle -> {FrontFaceColor -> Blue}]]], 1]
   Graphics[GraphicsComplex[{{1., 1.}, {1., 0.9285714285714285}, {1., 0.8571428571428571},
                             {1., 0.7857142857142857}, {1., 0.7142857142857142}, <<330>>,
                             {0.36186316312984096, 0.8086041639163778},
                             {0.3716571979394048, 0.42845000184937354}}, {<<2>>}], {<<1>>}]
```

As you might surmise from my use of `Short[]`, the internal structure is long and complicated. The interesting part is what's inside the `GraphicsComplex[]` object:

```
Shallow[InputForm[Cases[tst, GraphicsComplex[pts_, rest_] :> rest, ∞]], 8]
   {{Directive[{Hue[0.6, 0.3, 0.95], EdgeForm[{<< 1 >>}], EdgeForm[None], 
     Opacity[1], FrontFaceColor -> RGBColor[<< 3 >>], EdgeForm[None]}],
    {Annotation[Polygon[{<< 616 >>}], "Geometry"], {Directive[Opacity[<< 1 >>]],
     Point[{<< 337 >>}]}}}}
```

which finally reveals the reason for the behavior: **`FrontFaceColor -> Blue` is being used as a directive, and not as an option**. Because it is a directive, it is not subject to the inheritance rules for options.

It is a bit confusing, admittedly, but here is an even simpler demo of the same situation:

```
{Show[blank2, Graphics[{Polygon[{{0, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}, {0, 1}}]}, 
                       BaseStyle -> FrontFaceColor -> RGBColor[0, 0, 1]]], 
 Show[blank2, Graphics[GraphicsComplex[{{0, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}, {0, 1}},
                                       {FrontFaceColor -> RGBColor[0, 0, 1], 
                                        Polygon[{1, 2, 3, 4}]}]]]} // GraphicsRow
```

[image: result 3]

Comment: Thank you for this explanation! See my addendum above for my hypothesis of why my figures changed.

Answer (score 2):

`BaseStyle` for `Region` is not only a final's `Graphics'` option but is also passed inside the structure of `Graphics'` primitives.

The difference is that for `RegionDifference` it is included as `Polygon's` directive while for basic regions it is not.

This is why for basic regions this information is not preserved by `Show`. Because it only stays in options and they are ignored by `Show` in arguments past the first one.

See:

```
Developer`PackedArrayForm @ ToBoxes @ Region[uppercover, BaseStyle -> Blue]
```

[image]

vs

```
ToBoxes @ Region[square1, BaseStyle -> Blue]
```

> ```
> GraphicsBox[
>  TagBox[DynamicModuleBox[{...}, 
>    TagBox[{PolygonBox[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}], {}}, ...], 
>    ...], 
>   ...], {BaseStyle -> RGBColor[0, 0, 1], 
>   BaseStyle -> {
> Hue[0.6, 0.3, 0.95]}}]
> ```

So for `RegionDifference` `BaseStyle` behaves like e.g. `PlotStyle` for `Plot`. See remark about `PlotStyle/PlotMarkers` in [Plot Option Precedence while combining Plots with Show[]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128/plot-option-precedence-while-combining-plots-with-show)

Comment: Thank you for this explanation! See my addendum above for my hypothesis of why my figures changed.