# How is the scale of ParametricPlot3D determined?

Tags: plotting, graphics, parametric-functions

I define a couple `ParametricPlot3D` planes like so;

```
xyPlane = ParametricPlot3D[{0, y, z}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}];
yzPlane = ParametricPlot3D[{x, 0, z}, {x, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}];
```

Calling `Show` without `BoxRatios` returns

[image]

Whereas `BoxRatios -> {10, 10, 10}`

returns

[image]

Note the difference in gridlines. Is there some way to make them uniform? More generally, is it known what is going on under the hood of `ParametricPlot3d` that causes this?

Comment: You want AspectRatio as true BoxRatio for all three axes,  right?

Comment: I'm not sure. I am about to try messing with Mesh, but fundamentally I want to understand howParametricPlot3d decides this stuff.

Comment: @Narasimham, yes.

Comment: I had long felt that an option for automatic  proportional scaling was lacking in the Plot menu.

Comment: @Narasimham So, what setting should I use to get correct output?

Comment: @Narasimham, besides, why the hell doesn't BoxRatios do this correctly? In other words, why doesn't it produce 10 divisions form -5 to 5 instead of 10 divisions from -1 to 1?

Comment: Does `BoxRatios -> {5, 5, 1}` do what you want?

Comment: @BobHanlon no. To clarify,I am putting aspectratio on plane definitions and boxratio on the show statement

Comment: @BobHanlon I just want the same exact number of gridlines on both planes, and the same numebrs on both axes

Comment: @BobHanlon, interestingly enough sticking aspectratio into show throws the error `The specified setting for the option Graphics3DBoxOptions, AspectRatio cannot be used.`

Comment: If you want to faithfully plot a box $3 ^{'}X \,2 ^{'}X\,1 ^{'} $ then BoxRatios-> {3,2,1} has it plotted proportionally.

Comment: Before we all get hung up on `BoxRatios`: have you tried evaluating `Show[xyPlane, yzPlane, PlotRange -> All]`?

Comment: @J.M. Yes. That's it exactly.Thanks so much. But, why does ParametricPlot3d decide to chop things off like that?

Comment: Because of [option inheritance](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128) (in this specific case, the setting for `PlotRange`). Try evaluating `Show[yzPlane, xyPlane]`, and then try adding `PlotRange -> All` again.

Comment: @J.M. I would like to take a second to offer my best wishes and moral support (whatever that's worth) for your health problems. I would love to help you out, but sadly I am a poor undergraduate with health drama of my own. I really hope you get better.

Comment: The well-wishes are very much appreciated, and I hope you get well, too.