# How to replace an option value in a rules list captured by `OptionsPattern`?

Tags: functions, options

While experimenting with options, I tried to replace a value in the rules list captured by `OptionsPattern`. However, the following approach does not work as I expected:

```
f[opts:OptionsPattern[]]:= Hold[opts, a->3]
Column[{
    f[],
    f[a->1],
    f[a->1,b->2]
}]
```

> ```
> Hold[a->3]
> Hold[a->1,a->3]
> Hold[a->1,b->2,a->3]
> ```

I would have expected the value for the `a` option to be replaced. But instead, a new rule is added to the sequence.
So, is there a way to *replace* a rule in the option sequence?

Comment: "I would have expected the value for the a option to be replaced. But instead, a new rule is added to the sequence." - usually this is fine, since options are parsed left to right, and leftmost ones have higher priority. See e.g. [this older question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/128).

Comment: Yes, I already noticed that behavior when writing a thin wrapper around the `Plot` function. This question is mostly of theoretical concern while I'm studying more in-depth the Wolfram Language. So, let's pretend I really really want to _replace_ (or _delete_ BTW) a value in the options list ;)

Comment: So, something like the result of `DeleteDuplicatesBy[Join[{a -> 1, b -> 2}, {a -> 3}], First]`?

Comment: Maybe @J.M.. Right now, I was looking at [FilterRules](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FilterRules.html). It accepts the `FilterRules[..., Except[...]]` syntax that seems promising.

Comment: What about `FilterRules[{opts}, Except["a"]] // Append[a->3]`?

Answer (score 2):

As noticed by J.M. in a comment, it is usually *not* necessary to *replace* an option since *" options are parsed left to right, and leftmost ones have higher priority"* More details in [this older question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/128).

---

## Filtering rules

But let's pretend here I really really want to replace a rule in the options list. A possible solution in two steps would be:

1. Using [`FilterRules`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FilterRules.html) with the `FilterRules[..., Except[...]]` syntax we will first *delete* the rule we want to replace;
2. Using the classic list manipulation functions (like [`Append`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Append.html)) we will then add a new rule with the expected value.

```
f[opts:OptionsPattern[]] := FilterRules[{opts}, Except["a"]] // Append[a->3]
Column[{
    f[],
    f[a->1],
    f[b->2],
    f[a->1, b->2]
}]
```

Producing:

```
{a->3}
{a->3}
{b->2,a->3}
{b->2,a->3}
```

## Converting to an association

An alternate solution is to convert first the rules list to an association. In the process, duplicate rules replace their predecessor. Finally, using `Normal` we can convert back from an association to a list:

```
f[opts:OptionsPattern[]] := Normal[Association[opts, a->3]]
Column[{
    f[],
    f[a->1],
    f[b->2],
    f[a->1, b->2]
}]
```

Producing *almost* the same result as above:

```
{a->3}
{a->3}
{b->2,a->3}
{a->3,b->2}
```

As you can see, in the last test, the `a` value appears first--something that has some consistency with the notion or *replacement*, even if I'm not sure this behavior is guaranteed.